# From array create tuples on if condition python

Tags: python

I have an array:

```
['Booking.com', '$109', 'Hotels.com', '$109', 'Priceline', '$109', 
'Travelocity', '$109', 'eDreams', '$109', 'Hoteling', 'Otel.com']
```

I want to make it into tuples to make finding the lowest price easier.  However sometimes there are no prices associated with the field in front of it (Hoteling, Otel.com) so I want to ignore that in my tuple creation.

Final desired result:

```
[("Booking.com", "$109"), ("Hotels.com", "$109"), ("Priceline", "$109"), etc..
last element should be eDreams)]
```

I know I can do this creating a while loop and looping over it and checking the index after it to see if there is a "$" but I was hoping for a more pythonic way?

Comment: Why not use a dictionary?

Comment: hmmm never occurred to me, good idea. can I just use deafultdict(list)?

Comment: If you want to find the lowest price a heap would also be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a dictionary here would be more "Pythonic", but you can use a list comprehension to do what you want with the list that you have:

```
In [4]: [(a[i], a[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(a)-1,2) if a[i+1].startswith('$')]
Out[4]: 
[('Booking.com', '$109'),
 ('Hotels.com', '$109'),
 ('Priceline', '$109'),
 ('Travelocity', '$109'),
 ('eDreams', '$109')]
```

To get a dictionary, you could either pass your list of tuples to `dict()` or use:

```
In [4]: {a[i]:a[i+1] for i in range(0,len(a)-1,2) if a[i+1].startswith('$')}
Out[4]: 
{'Booking.com': '$109',
 'Hotels.com': '$109',
 'Priceline': '$109',
 'Travelocity': '$109',
 'eDreams': '$109'}
```

Comment: @RNar Yep, that's probably faster too.

Comment: dumb question, do I have to init a dictionary, I am trying:  {compare[i]:compare[i+1] for i in range(0,len(compare),2) if compare[i+1].startswith('$')}   and I get global name compare not found?

Comment: @TestDev I was taking my `a` to be the list you provide at the top of your question. If this is what you are calling `compare`, then maybe check that it is properly defined. You don't need to initialise an empty dictionary first with a dict comprehension.

Comment: Last Question: I just tried with this array: ['Booking.com', '$142', 'Hotels.com', '$142', 'HRS.com', '$141', 'Priceline', '$142', 'Hotwire.com', '$142', 'BookIt', '$142', 'getaroom.com', '$142', 'Travelocity', '$142', 'eDreams', '$142', 'amextravel.com', 'Hoteling', 'HotelTravel.com', 'Orbitz.com', 'AMOMA'].  And I get error index out of bounds?  so no dict was formed?

Comment: @TestDev My bad -- I think you need to iterate with `range(0,len(a)-1,2)` so that you always have an item at the last index plus one: I've edited my answer.